# Fedora 18 yum update transcation check error conflicts between attempted installs of colord

Tags: fedora, yum

A friend asked me to install Fedora 18 from DVD with XFC on a new laptop and gave me a few packages he determined that he needed.

I installed F18 with XFC as the window manager with no problem,
I then applied these yum updates:

```
sudo yum install fontconfig-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install freetype-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install gdk-pixbuf2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install gl-manpages.noarch
sudo yum install glib.x86_64
sudo yum install glib-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install glib2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install gtk+.x86_64
sudo yum install gtk+-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64
sudo yum install gtk2-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install guile.x86_64
sudo yum install harfbuzz-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install khrplatform-devel.noarch
sudo yum install libICE-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libSM-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libX11-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXau-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXcomposite-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXcursor-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXdamage-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXext.x86_64
sudo yum install libXext-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXfixes-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXft-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXi-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXinerama-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXrandr-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXrender-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXt-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libXxf86vm-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libdrm-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libpng-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libxcb-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install mesa-libEGL-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install msttcore-fonts.noarch
sudo yum install mtd-utils.x86_64
sudo yum install ncurses-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install pango-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install perl-Text-CSV.noarch
sudo yum install perl-Text-CSV-Separator.noarch
sudo yum install pixman-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install tkcvs.noarch
sudo yum install uboot-tools.x86_64
sudo yum install zlib-devel.x86_64
```

That seemed to go OK, but I then did a yum update for good measure and got this:

```
...
Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================
Install    6 Packages (+58 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  379 Packages

Total size: 326 M
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/AdobeRGB1998.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/AppleRGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/CIE-RGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ColorMatchRGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/NTSC-RGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/PAL-RGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/ProPhotoRGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/SMPTE-C-RGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/SwappedRedAndGreen.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/bluish.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/gamma5000.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/gamma5500.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/gamma6500.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64
  file /usr/share/color/icc/colord/x11-colors.icc conflicts between attempted installs of colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.i686 and colord-0.1.31-1.fc18.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

How do I diagnose the root cause and resolve it.  On one attempt I tried removing colord ... that was bad... I ended up with no window manager.

Thank you,
David

Comment: You did not apply updates, but installed packages instead. Looks like the system was installed with 32-bit packages and then you installed conflicting 64-bit packages. You could try running `yum list updates` and then try applying them one at a time with `yum update` for each listed package.

Comment: @DavidGamache Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) because it is not about programming or software development. You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I had updated to FC18 from FC17.
It is looks like colord.i686 is required by skype.
I just delete it with skype.